# Cannot initiate a successful connection from private subnet to public subnet

Tags: amazon-ec2, nat, subnet, vpc

I have an instance in private subnet. I have two more instances in public subnet including a NAT instance. From NAT and another public instance  I am able to ping/ssh to the instance in private subnet successfully but the reverse case is not working. First I was trying to find out why the private instance is not connecting to the internet but then I realized it is not even connecting to public subnet. Security rules are allowing all traffic(inbound and outbound) for all the instances and even the routing tables are correct. What is the reason for this? Is there anything that is stopping the private subnet from connecting to the public subnet, because as I understood within a VPC all instances can communicate to each other no matter what subnet they belong to?

Comment: Can you provide the routing tables you have set for both subnets? That's the most likely candidate in my experience, Are you using an Amazon provided NAT AMI, or your own? Have you modified the network ACL's at all? Also can you provide any error messages or are network requests just timing out?

Comment: I think it's not the issue with NAT. When I tried to ping from instance in private subnet to another instance in public subnet, it didn't work. I am able to connect from public subnet to private subnet and get the response back but not able to initiate a connection from private subnet to public subnet. What could be the possible issue here?

Comment: The causes that come to mind are:
Routing Tables, 
Network ACL, 
Security Groups, 
OS Firewall. 

Its most likely your route tables (in my experience) can you please post them - for both subnets? Additionally have you made any changes to your network ACLs?

The reason I asked about the AMI was that it could be an OS firewall on the instance in the public subnet. If you are using the AWS provided one this can be ruled out.